# How to optimize deployment to regions for minimum perceived latency and maximum cost savings?

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions, latency

I will be using Azure Cosmos DB with Azure Functions deployed in the same regions, with a gateway (cloudflare or an Azure option) which will route to the azure function in the closest region, which is deployed along side a Cosmos DB replication.

the benefits in perceived latency should be logarithmic right?
[image]
like, having 2 regions is 3x better,
3 region ~5x times better perceived latency. etc.

according to MS, Cosmos DB is available in all regions.
[image]
considering our customers aren't clustered around a specific region and are all over the world.
which is the optimal regions to deploy to?
[image]

for replication in

1. 1 region
2. 2 regions
3. 3 regions
4. 4 regions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the http://www.azurespeed.com/
to see the closest DC from the client and pick the optimal location.

Answer (score 0):

As an extreme/unrealistic case you can imagine each customer/client having a copy of the db running next to them. This should cause the least latency for the customer. Right ?

The answer is that **it depends**. If you talk about local read/write latency then that would be true. However, the more you replicate your database the more time write operations will take to synchronise across all nodes (and in turn affect what is available when you read). See consistency models [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels). Although you have customers spread across the globe, it would be better if you start from regions with the most load/requests and then spread out from there.

Deciding this is also when the proverbial "rubber meets the road" as you would soon realise that business might be willing to relax some latency needs around edges given the cost increase to achieve 100% coverage.